# .NET version not installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

I am having an issue running a .exe program on linux.

I am currently using the wine framework to execute the program, but when i launch it the application raises an error that has the following title:
**NET version not installed**

and the following content:

```
The secure Browser requires a minimum .NET version of 4.6.2 or higher. Please install it and try again.
```

I went on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu website as they offer a quick tutorial on how to install the .NET SDK or the .NET Runtime on Ubuntu.

I then ran these commands:

**Installing Microsoft packages**

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/21.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

**Install the SDK**

```
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

Install the runtime

```
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-6.0
```

But still when i try to run the program i get the same exact error. What am i missing here?

Note that i have also tried to run the program with **mono** but apparently i cant do that since i get this output:

```
Cannot open assembly 'filename.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

**Probably unrelated:**
When i run the program using wine i also get this error on the console:

```
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a confusing but important difference between the [.net framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework) and the [.net core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet).   Any .net version 4.x.x is referencing to the .net framework.  .net 3,5,6 are referring to the .net core.

Unfortunately .net framework is a component of windows and can't be installed on linux.  If an app was written for the .net framework (especially GUI apps), it won't usually work with the .net core.

Comment: Thank you, it makes a lot of sense. I also tried to install a virtual machine on my linux and i ran the app on windows. Now it says that the app won't run inside of a virtual machine. At this point should i just dual boot to run this file?

Comment: It should work in the virtual machine as long as you have Windows installed and you're running the program in the virtual machine.  Maybe you can double check the version of the .net framework you have installed using this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed .  You might need to update the framework if you're using an older version